# Auto Increment not working for Entity class with composite Key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, entity

I want one of my Composite key elements to be auto incremented and I am using Embedded Key for my entity class and therefore I am not able to use the Generated Values Annotation to solve the problem since `@GeneratedValue` annotation is ignored when using `@Embeddable` or `@EmbeddedId`.

Comment: Auto increment is a Hibernate/JPA feature, but has nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: I'm Using this in Spring and therefore the tag

Comment: I understand you, but trust me, Spring has really nothing to do with Hibernat Auto Increament.

Comment: But in my current usage, The database is being generated by Spring! So any method to generate the Database with my key field as auto-increment would also help me! therefore I thought it was worth mentioning!

Comment: I you do not trust me (I am using Spring and Hibernate for more then 9 years on a professional day by day basis), then add this tags again and rename you question.

Comment: I totally trust you and I started using spring just 3 weeks ago. So you're the expert here. And with your experience, along with modifying my question you could've provided a solution or pointed out that it was totally impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `@GeneratedValue` with `@EmbeddedId`, `@Embeddable` or `@IdClass`, the `@GeneratedValue` annotation gets ignored. 
**You have to manually assign the values.**

Check the following references :

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-13567

https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2393944&sid=57b20ef2c7de6f6bcba632130987bc22

Comment: You can use sequence generator https://thorben-janssen.com/composite-primary-keys-sequence/

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong, but i will give you the response:

Use something like that to get the next val and set before your save.

In Repository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SQ_CD_PLANO.nextVal FROM dual", nativeQuery = true)
Long getNextSequence();
```

In service:

```
Long nextVal = planHistRepository.getNextSequence();
planHist.getPlanHistId().setPlanCode(nextVal);
PlanHist planHistSaved = planHistRepository.save(planHist);
```

Why is it wrong? Because @EmbeddedId ignore @GeneratedValue inside itself. But the work around that i pass will make you smile.

Note: I use ORACLE DATABASE in this demonstration.
Note2: SQ_CD_PLANO is the sequence created for the auto increment.