# Foreign key not saved by hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

In a spring boot 2 project with hibernate and jpa,

I try to save some object

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbedddedSamplesKey implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private int year;
    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(EmbedddedSamplesKey.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    private int year;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sampling", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Samples> samples = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addSample(Samples sample) {
      samples.add(sample);
      sample.setSampling(this);
    }

    public void removeSample(Samples sample) {
      samples.remove(sample);
      sample.setSampling(null);
    }

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Samples extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "samples_id_seq", sequenceName = "samples_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "samples_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    private String letter;

    //@OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    //private TestSamples testSamples;

    @ManyToOne
    private Samplings sampling;
    ...
}
```

When I save Sampling, I see in the table of samples then

sampling_id
sampling_year

are not feed

It's supposed to be the orm job to do that?

In Samples, orm have generate this

```
ALTER TABLE samples
  ADD CONSTRAINT fkq5if151jgtlcy7yfp55ffvf47 FOREIGN KEY (sampling_id, sampling_year)
  REFERENCES samplings (id, year)
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Edit, tried

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")})
private Samplings sampling;
```

but same result

Also, If in Samples I would like to use like Sampling primary + field letter like primary key is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible contrary to what Nicholas says

just check this example

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/ceaeb81e3362ff187004ea3479b2afeeba5aa8a6/documentation/src/test/java/org/hibernate/userguide/mapping/identifier/IdClassGeneratedValueTest.java#L77

Change to cascade.all, should help... probably sprind data to a merge instead of a persist.

maybe a spring boot issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the @JoinColumn annotation:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sampling")
private Samplings sampling;
```

Comment: tried... but get   wrong number of column. should be 2

Comment: Do you have a column named sampling in the table Samples??

Comment: because IdClass is used, in samples: two column are created sampling_id, sampling_year

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer, but better to wait 3 month to get a answer.... time is money

If don't know need to do any special operation on sequence....

just use the sequence, add a transient field who will be a sequence + year....

Comment: not crazy, but surely possible to do what i want.... don't seem so complex like feature

Answer (score 0):

On cursory glance, I don't think you can use @GeneratedValue with @IdClass.

[Auto Increment not working for Entity class with composite Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115642/auto-increment-not-working-for-entity-class-with-composite-key)